# Python 3 sign a message with key sha512

Tags: python, security, authentication, hmac, sha512

I have the following line of code:

```
return hmac.new(self.Secret.upper() , message , hashlib.sha512).digest().encode("base64").replace("\n","")
```

This works fine in Python2, but not in Python 3. As soon as I try in Python 3 I get:

```
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
```

from `hmac.py`. I've of course tried converting `self.Secret` and `message` using `bytes()` and `bytearray()`, but that hasn't worked either.

I've also tried using `hashlib.sha512` to generate the key, but that's not very clear to me. I have a secret API key that needs to be used to sign the POST data and the only clear way to do this is using `hmac.new()`, but when I finally do get something that can be passed as a string it looks nothing like it should, and as expected I can't authenticate with it.

Another attempt was:

```
sign = hashlib.sha512(message_to_sign)
sign.update(self.Secret.upper())
```

This also produces a string that looks nothing like the working key that comes from the original code in Python 2.7.

I've tried so many other variations as well, but none of them give me anything that works.

Comment: In python3, hmac.new(...) accepts **key** as bytes/bytearray, not string (as the error suggested, and differences between py2 handling strings/bytes). So you probably need to convert it like `bytes(self.Secret().upper(), "utf-8")`...

Comment: Yea, I've tried that. That's what I meant when I said I tried converting them. I used bytearray() and bytes(), but neither did it for me. However, I now have a valid looking key, I'm not sure it's right because I'm not using my key to sign the post data. I'm also getting a new error from the API about an invalid header name, which doesn't make any sense since I'm only including the ones they tell me to use. This happens if I use python-requests or pycurl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one works for me on python 3.4.2:

```
print((base64.b64encode(hmac.new(bytearray("SECRET".upper(), "ASCII") , bytearray("TEST","ASCII") , hashlib.sha512).digest())).decode("ASCII").replace("\n", ""))
```

...and calculates a correct HMAC.

You might want to change `"ASCII"` to some other encoding.

Comment: Finally! I've been at this for hours. Freaking ASCII, I kept trying unicode and base64 on everything, and only ASCII once. Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't see how b64encode is justified here. The python2 code doesn' t do it. The encoding needs to match whatever other bits of code that check the signature expect.

Comment: Yeah, but that's after the hashing. Your code will generate a different hash than the original example.

Comment: @tdelaney the `.digest()` is inside the `base64.b64encode` call

Answer (score 2):

`hmac` hashing works with binary keys and data. In python2, `str` is a sequence of 8 bit characters which is interchangable with binary so everything works. In python3, `str` is a sequence of unicode characters and must be encoded to binary to work. This should work:

```
return hmac.new(bytes(self.Secret.upper().encode('ascii')) , bytes(message.encode('ascii') , hashlib.sha512).digest().encode("base64").replace("\n","")
```

Notice I used `ascii` encoding but that's just a guess. Your python2 strings may be your local code page and your message may be a binary blob already. You'll need to formalize what encoding you use so that receivers know how to verify the signature.

Comment: Yea, it was the ascii encoding. Thanks!

Comment: 'utf-8' may be a better choice long term, but you may find that old stuff you've already signed won't work.